# Trouble making checkboxes required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm looking for some help regarding making checkboxes required.

I'm build a form, based on bootstrap 4. I'm validating the form by the JS example in bootstrap documentation, by adding "novalidate" to form, adding "required" to inputs, and adding the following script:

```
  (function() {
  'use strict';
   window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('forms');
     form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
       }
      form.classList.add('was-validated');

      }, false);
      }, false);
  })();
```

Everything is going smoothly, but now I got a few checkboxes, and I would like to only validate it if user checks at least one. I was wondering, if I should make a different function to validate this, or build on the current one. Whichever the case, I'd be very grateful if someone could help me out.

This is the code for the checkboxes:

```
    <div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label for="checkboxes">Indícios:</label>
  <div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" id="" type="checkbox" value="1">
    1
  </label>
</div>

  <div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="2">
    2
  </label>
</div>

  <div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="3">
    3
  </label>
</div>

  <div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="4">
    4
  </label>
</div>

  <div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="5">
    5
  </label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">

<label for="checkboxes1">&nbsp</label>
  <div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkboxes1" value="6">
    6
  </label>
</div>

  <div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="7">
    7.
  </label>
</div>

  <div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="8">
    8
  </label>
</div>

  <div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="9">
    9
  </label>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that you use jQuery here is a function you can add to you checkValidity method

```
function checkCheckboxes = function() {
    return ($('.form-check-input:checked').length > 0);
};
```

this functions checks if there is any input with class .form-check-input and with the :checked state is available in the html. When it is, the checkbox-validation is valid.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I really think this is what I need, I'm having trouble with where to add that function inside my own tho. Been trying but can't seem to make it work out.

By the way, by adding it to the checkValidity method, then the validation styling will be applied to the checkbox also, right? That would be awesome.